# How do I print specfic parts of a string in a file

Tags: c, etcpasswd

I'm writing a program that will read from `/etc/passwd` and output the username and shell.

For example, here is the first line:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

I need to only output the user and the shell. In this instance it would print:

```
root:/bin/bash
```

The values are seperated by `:` so I just need to print the string before the first `:` and the string after the 6th `:`. How can I do that?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//printf and scanf prototype

int printf(const char *text, ...);
int scanf(const char *format, ...);

int main(void)
{
        int fd;
        int buff_size = 1;
        char buff[512];
        int size;
        fd = open("/etc/passwd",O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
                printf("Error opening file \n");
                return -1;
        }
        while ((size = read(fd,buff,1))>0)
        {
                buff[1] = '\0';
                printf("%s",buff);
        }
}
```

So far the code reads from `/etc/passwd` and prints out the whole file line by line. I need to configure the `printf` statement to just print the user and shell for each instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is how to modify a string; all of the code you've written so far is irrelevant to the problem. Do you know anything about how to modify a string?

Comment: Why are you making your own prototypes for standard functions like `printf()` instead of a `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: ([`getpwent()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) is the easy way to do this)

Comment: @Shawn the assignment requires us to not use stdio.h and stdlib.h

Comment: @Shawn getpwent() looks like thats what i need, but im a little confused by the syntax and how to use it

Comment: @beta I know a bit how to but i dont know how to only print specfic parts of a line

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to print the string before the first `:` and the string after the 6th `:`.

Filter the string, put the needed data into an output buffer, and print the output buffer.

Since you already used `char buff[512];` as the original data buffer, then just create another buffer for output. i.e. `char outbuff[512];`

```c
// char buff[512];     assume already defined as that in PO
// char outbuff[512];  assume already defined as that in PO
void customized_print(char* buff, char* outbuff) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, cnt = 0;
    while (i < 512) {   // copy until first ':'
        if((outbuff[j++]=buff[i++]) == ':') break;
    }
    // skip 5 more ':'
    while (i < 512 && cnt < 5) {
        if(buff[i++] == ':') cnt++;
    } 
    // copy the remains
    while (i < 512) {
        if( (outbuff[j++]=buff[i++]) == '\0' ) break; 
    }
    printf("%s\n", outbuff); 
    outbuff[0] = 0;  // clean the outbuff 
}
```

##### Another solution with a demo of full code.

If you do not need to use `buff`. You can use the following solution.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
void customized_print(char* buff, char* outbuff) {
    int cnt = 0;
    char* p = outbuff;
    while (*buff) {   // copy until first ':'
        if((*p++=*buff++) == ':') break;
    }
    // skip 5 more ':'
    while (*buff && cnt < 5) {
        if(*buff++ == ':') cnt++;
    }
    // copy the remains
    while (*buff) {
        if( (*p++=*buff++) == '\0' ) break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", outbuff);
    outbuff[0]=0;  // clean the outbuff
}

int main(){
    char outbuff[512];
    customized_print("root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash", outbuff);
    customized_print("foo:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash", outbuff);
    return 0;
}
```

- Compile and run:

  ```
  gcc -Wall demo.c -o demo.out
  ./demo.out
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  root:/bin/bash
  foo:/bin/bashh
  ```

Comment: how would i call that function in my code? i run it and it prints nothing

Comment: @Mozart Here are some steps I recommend you to do: 1. read and understand my solution. 2. try to run my solution (that's why I provide a ready-to-use build command). 3. there are several issues in your code, and you need to fix them.  4. copy my code to use.    There are some references that might be helpful.  * [a good main](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/how-write-good-c-main-function)   *[File IO in c](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output).